# LG Optimus G Pro E985 - How to make pictures more colorful

Tags: camera

I have this phone and it takes good pictures, but they are too bland - there is no life in colors, and they are low contrast and too white-ish. How do I increase the colors presence?

Here is one of the images I've taken

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the colors are washed out even on automatic mode and good lighting, it may be a hardware issue. Best option might be to use a 3rd party app to increase the photos' vibrance. I personally use [Perfectly Clear](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.worldiety.athentech.perfectlyclear) and [Pixlr Express](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pixlr.express) to improve colors on my Samsung Galaxy S4.

Comment: you mean I cant just change the settings of my camera, I should edit the images after ive taken them? I dont think its a hardware issue, the phone is almost new. I am going to add an image to my question so you can see it

Comment: @J.Kowalski Take a look at this comparison done by Phone Arena. You will notice that the LG Optimus G Pro's colors are really washed out. http://www.phonearena.com/reviews/Samsung-Galaxy-S4-vs-LG-Optimus-G-Pro_id3296/page/3

Comment: well I like those. they look better than mine :)